# How to add two controls s in one column of ui grid angularjs

Tags: angular-ui-grid

Kindly let me know how to add two controls in one column of AngularJS ui-grid table. We have requirement to have two controls in one.
Don't know how to achieve this.

Thanks and regards,
Arti

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What two controls?  And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to add some buttons that perform actions on the grid row that you are in you can simply add a column like so.

e.g.

```
{
    name: 'actions',
    displayName: 'Actions',
    enableCellEdit: false,
    cellTemplate: 'Actions.html'
}
```

Then put the buttons into the html file.

e.g.

```
<span>
    <a href ng-click="grid.appScope.action(row.entity)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
</span>
```

This allows you to put a function into your controller that is referred to via the grid.appScope. and pass it the row.entity, which is the data from the row.